# Cannot redirect after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, redirect

I have a form on a HTML page that has form data, and would like to have the user redirected to a new URL page after they have pressed the submit button and it has emailed the information. The form is called with the following button.

```
<div class="btnp"><input type="submit"  value="Continue to Billing" ></div>
```

The form then sends the data to my PHP file via post. I do not need a success echo message, I would just like the URL to be redirected to the payment page. Below is the PHP file I have set up. I am trying to submit, send email with form date, and then redirect to a new html url.

```
<?php
//Retrieve form data. 
//POST
$URL = "http://www.google.com"; 
$fname  = $_POST['fname'];              
$zip = $_POST['zip'];       
$phone = $_POST['phone'];       
$email = $_POST['email'];       

    //recipient - change this to your name and email
    $to = 'sales@mysite.com';   
    //sender
    $from = $fname . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message
    $subject = 'New User: ' . $fname;   
    $message = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>First Name</td><td>' . $fame . '</td></tr>      
            <tr><td>Zip</td><td>' . $zip . '</td></tr>      
            <tr><td>Telephone</td><td>' . $phone . '</td></tr>  
            <tr><td>Email</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>  
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    //send the mail
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

    if ($_POST) 
        if ($result) header('Location: '.$URL);
        else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

    //Simple mail function with HTML header
    function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";  
    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }       
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to use jQuery/AJAX or Form POST to submit the form?  You try both.  `header('Location: '.$url);` won't work if your submitting with AJAX.

Comment: I may be wrong but since I am only using the POST method, and not calling GET am I not using AJAX and so the header method should work right? 

I have no preference to which method I use as long as the email sends with a successful redirect. Thanks

Comment: Is there a snippet of code I am using that calls for GET and I should remove?

Comment: I have edited my original code trying to condense it and remove any unnecessary parts. While also trying to implement what has been offered here.

Comment: Sanitize your POST parameters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `header('Location: $url);` snippet that your tried but correct the function to this:

```
header('Location: '.$URL);
```

just make sure the varibale `$URL` is defined.

Comment: Okay, I defined a URL at the top of the list where I gathered the data via post.  
$URL = "http://www.google.com"; Then I used header('Location: '.$URL);   At the very bottom of the file, the email still sends but I don't get redirected.

Answer (score 2):

To use the "header" function:

```
header("location: result.php");
```

You can't output/print/echo anything to the screen, so try this:

```
if ($_POST) 
        if ($result) header("location: result-page.php");
        else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';
```

Or you can use javascript to print the success msg and redirect:

```
if ($_POST) 
        if ($result) { 
            print "<script>alert('Ok, email sent');</script>";
            print "<script>window.open('result-page.php','_self');</script>";
        }else{
            print 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';
        }
```

Comment: Thank you both for helping me. Continueing with the defined URL at the top of my form I tried using the first option you gave me if ($_POST)... but I replaced the header("location: result-page.php");
with header('Location: '.$URL);      Again I placed this code at the very bottom, sends but no redirect. I try moving it around however. 

I would like to redirect to a html page.

Comment: use the "exit(0)" function after call header("Location: ".$URL)... so the script will end and redirect.